# Enable encryption at rest in SQS for serverless

Tags: amazon-web-services, encryption, aws-cloudformation, amazon-sqs

We are using serverless framework for our application with microservices (lambda functions). In the serverless.yml file we list down the resources which need to be created upon deployment.

The resources section of the serverles.yml file looks like the following:

```
resources:
    Resources:
        GatewayResponse:
            Type: "AWS::ApiGateway::GatewayResponse"
            Properties:
                ResponseParameters:
                    gatewayresponse.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "'*'"
                    gatewayresponse.header.Access-Control-Allow-Headers: "'*'"
                ResponseType: EXPIRED_TOKEN
                RestApiId:
                    Ref: "ApiGatewayRestApi"
                StatusCode: "401"
        AuthFailureGatewayResponse:
            Type: "AWS::ApiGateway::GatewayResponse"
            Properties:
                ResponseParameters:
                    gatewayresponse.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "'*'"
                    gatewayresponse.header.Access-Control-Allow-Headers: "'*'"
                ResponseType: UNAUTHORIZED
                RestApiId:
                    Ref: "ApiGatewayRestApi"
                StatusCode: "401"
        SqsQueue:
            Type: "AWS::SQS::Queue"
            Properties:
                QueueName: ${opt:stage}-${opt:product}-sqs-queue
                VisibilityTimeout: 900
                RedrivePolicy:
                    deadLetterTargetArn:
                        Fn::GetAtt:
                        - SqsDeadLetterQueue
                        - Arn
                    maxReceiveCount: 1
        SqsDeadLetterQueue:
            Type: AWS::SQS::Queue
            Properties:
                QueueName: ${opt:stage}-${opt:product}-deadletter-queue
                MessageRetentionPeriod: 1209600
```

As you can see we are creating the SQS queue resource there as well. Initially we had not enabled encryption for rest in our SQS but now the need has arised.

I can go into the AWS console and enable encryption at rest manually from there for each and every queue we have created but it will be tedious, also I want to include it in the serverless.yml creation so any SQS resources created from now on have encryption enabled by default.

I would like to know what I need to add to the resource section of serverless.yml. Do I add the CMK (customer master key) alias, can I use a default CMK alias or do I need to generate a new one for this purpose. Do I also need to modify other lambdas which are referring the SQS so they are able to access it?

Comment: How did it go? The issue still persists?

Comment: @Marcin, going to update the serverless.yml today and will respond back here. Gonna try with one lambda and see if other lambda using the queue can call it.

Comment: @Marcin, it worked. my other lambda function was able to call the encrypted sqs queue. thank you for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To add encryption to your queues you have to add [KmsMasterKeyId](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-sqs-queue.html#cfn-sqs-queue-kmsmasterkeyid) to your queues in the template. If you want to use AWS managed CMK, the id will be `alias/aws/sqs` (assuming both queues):

```
resources:
    Resources:
        GatewayResponse:
            Type: "AWS::ApiGateway::GatewayResponse"
            Properties:
                ResponseParameters:
                    gatewayresponse.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "'*'"
                    gatewayresponse.header.Access-Control-Allow-Headers: "'*'"
                ResponseType: EXPIRED_TOKEN
                RestApiId:
                    Ref: "ApiGatewayRestApi"
                StatusCode: "401"
        AuthFailureGatewayResponse:
            Type: "AWS::ApiGateway::GatewayResponse"
            Properties:
                ResponseParameters:
                    gatewayresponse.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "'*'"
                    gatewayresponse.header.Access-Control-Allow-Headers: "'*'"
                ResponseType: UNAUTHORIZED
                RestApiId:
                    Ref: "ApiGatewayRestApi"
                StatusCode: "401"
        SqsQueue:
            Type: "AWS::SQS::Queue"
            Properties:
                QueueName: ${opt:stage}-${opt:product}-sqs-queue
                VisibilityTimeout: 900
                RedrivePolicy:
                    deadLetterTargetArn:
                        Fn::GetAtt:
                        - SqsDeadLetterQueue
                        - Arn
                    maxReceiveCount: 1
                KmsMasterKeyId: alias/aws/sqs
        SqsDeadLetterQueue:
            Type: AWS::SQS::Queue
            Properties:
                QueueName: ${opt:stage}-${opt:product}-deadletter-queue
                MessageRetentionPeriod: 1209600
                KmsMasterKeyId: alias/aws/sqs
```

Comment: Will adding the encryption at rest (be it KmsMasterKeyId or even AWS managed CMK) to the SQS have any effect on the other lambdas which might be using these resources? So I have other lambdas where I am call the above created sqs queue, would i need to pass anything there?

Comment: @codeinprogress I think it should be transparent. If you want, you can check it on some dummy sqs and lambda function.

Comment: if I need to encrypt my S3 buckets on rest do I do the same thing in my serverless.yml as well

Comment: @codeinprogress Yes, buckets also have similar encryption settings.